# css: sort divs/lis into two columns

Tags: css, css-position

Suppose there are two kinds of elements, let's say words and numbers. They should be sorted into two columns. For the example I'm using listitems, but I don't mind changing to divs or something else if that helps.

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li class="num">1</li>
        <li class="num">2</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Right now I'm achieving this somewhat by using margins, with the following css:

```css
#container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;   
}

li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-right: 300px;
}

.num {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

resulting in

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/he13vug4/

What would be a more elegant way to achieve this?

How could I make the numbers "start" (in terms of vertical position) already besides "bar" or even "foo"? (The next word should, however, only start below the numbers). That is, I'd like

[image]

or

[image]

instead of

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> They should be sorted into two columns, side by side

Do you need support for older browsers? If not, CSS Grid could help you

### Result

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.word {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.num {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li class="word">foo</li>
  <li class="word">bar</li>
  <li class="num">1</li>
  <li class="num">2</li>
  <li class="word">baz</li>
</ul>
```

And same code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hisbvdis/6nt5pex0/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use only left floating and play with clear and margin like below:

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
ul {
 list-style:none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
li + li:not(.num) {
  clear:both;
}
li + li.num {
  margin-left:10px;
}
li.num + li.num {
  margin-left:210px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li class="num">1</li>
    <li class="num">2</li>
    <li>baz</li>
    <li>baz</li>
    <li class="num">1</li>
    <li class="num">2</li>
    <li class="num">3</li>
    <li>baz</li>
    <li>baz</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```